# ExternallyOwned() doesn't work on Assembly Scanning level?

Tags: c#, autofac

I have the following classes inside the Assembly `AutofacDotMemory`

```
public interface IOutput:IDisposable
{
    void Write(string content);
}


public class ConsoleOutput : IOutput
{
    public void Write(string content)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(content);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // TODO release managed resources here
    }
}


public interface IDateWriter:IDisposable
{
    void WriteDate();
}



public class TodayWriter : IDateWriter
{
    private IOutput _output;
    public TodayWriter( IOutput output)
    {
        this._output = output;
    }

    public void WriteDate()
    {
        this._output.Write(DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString());
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // TODO release managed resources here
    }
}
```

And in my another test assembly I've also referred to Autofac and I try to use ExternallyOwned at assembly scanning level, with the following test code:

```
    [Test]
    public void ExternallyOwnedTest()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();


        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(IDateWriter).Assembly)
            .ExternallyOwned();

        builder.RegisterType<ConsoleOutput>().As<IOutput>();
        builder.RegisterType<TodayWriter>().As<IDateWriter>();


        var container = builder.Build();

        var registration = container.ComponentRegistry.TryGetRegistration(new TypedService(typeof(IDateWriter)), out var foundRegistration);

        TestContext.WriteLine(registration);

        var isExternallyOwned = registration && foundRegistration.Ownership == InstanceOwnership.ExternallyOwned;

        Assert.IsTrue(isExternallyOwned, $"{nameof(TodayWriter)} is not externally owned");
        container.Dispose();
    }
```

And the test **fails** because `TodayWriter` is not ExternallyOwned.

But if I change the registration code to the below, so that it's done on per registration type basis:

```
 var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    
    builder.RegisterType<ConsoleOutput>().As<IOutput>();
    builder.RegisterType<TodayWriter>().As<IDateWriter>().ExternallyOwned(); //now this works
    
    
    var container = builder.Build();
    
    var registration = container.ComponentRegistry.TryGetRegistration(new TypedService(typeof(IDateWriter)), out var foundRegistration);
    
   TestContext.WriteLine(registration);
    
   var isExternallyOwned = registration && foundRegistration.Ownership == InstanceOwnership.ExternallyOwned;
    
    Assert.IsTrue(isExternallyOwned, $"{nameof(TodayWriter)} is not externally owned");
    container.Dispose();
```

And now this test passes because `TodayWriter` is externally owned.

How to ensure that all of the types in a given assembly ( or at least the majority of the types, subjected to a `Where` filter condition) is registered as ExternallyOwned? I don't want to go through all of the registered type and add an ExternallyOwned keyword there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your test...

```cs
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(IDateWriter).Assembly)
            .ExternallyOwned();

        builder.RegisterType<ConsoleOutput>().As<IOutput>();
        builder.RegisterType<TodayWriter>().As<IDateWriter>();
```

You registered `TodayWriter` twice. Once through the assembly scanning, once manually.

In the assembly scanning it got registered as `ExternallyOwned`. But then you *overrode* that and registered it as normal, which is *not* `ExternallyOwned`. In registrations, last in wins.

Comment: Is there anyway, for the second registration, to register everything else about the `IDataWriter`, __except__ for the `ExternallyOwned ` property?

Comment: No, there's not.